# How can i find the solution for Dialpad problem?

Tags: java, algorithm, data-structures

P.S This is not a homework question, neither asking for full code.
question begin as-

You are given an old touch smartphone numbers having dial pad and calculator app.

Aim: The goal is to type a number on dialpad. But as phone is old, some of the numbers and some operations can’t be touched.  For eg. 2,3,5,9 keys are not responding , i.e you cannot use them  But you can always make a number using other numbers and operations in Calculator. There could be multiple ways of making a number. Calculator have 1-9 and +,-,*,/,= as operations. Once you have made the number in Calculator you can copy the number and use it. You have to find minimum number to touches required to obtain a number.

I tried backtracking and several other sources for a possible way of solving such question.

## Input:

There will be multiple Test cases .Each test case will consist of 4 lines

1. First line will consist of N,M,O

   - N: no of keys working in Dialpad (out of 0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9)
   - M: types of operations supported (+,-,*,/)
   - O: Max no of touches allowed
2. second line of input contains the digits that are working e.g 0,2,3,4,6.
3. Third line contains the valued describing operations, 1(+),2(-),3(*),4(/)
4. fourth line contains the number that we want to make .

## Output:

Output contains 1 line printing the number of touches required to make the number

## Sample Test Case:

```
1 // No of test cases
5 3 5 // N ,M, O
1 2 4 6 0 // digits that are working (total number of digits = N),
1 2 3 // describing operations allowed (1–> ‘+’, 2–> ‘-‘, 3–> ‘*’ , 4–> ‘/’ )(total number is equals to M)
5 // number we want to make
```

Answer 3
How 4? 1+4= , “=” is also counted as a touch.

Comment: This is a [Samsung Interview Question](https://www.careercup.com/question?id=5680648437104640)

Comment: Why did backtracking not work for you?

Comment: Didn't get a possible solution with given constraint using backtracking.

Comment: What was your basic approach? Pseudocode or code.

Comment: This problem is not well defined at all. Does the calculator understand that * and / binds stronger than + and -? Does copying a previously built number count as one touch or two (copy+paste) or something else? E.g. could we build 424242 by typing 42 copy paste paste? If I type 1+2+5 is the intermediate result 3 displayed and can be copied or not? Is it integer division? Can we only copy parts of a number? So many questions...

Comment: i think you didn't read it properly.A dial pad has limited restricted inputs and moreover every character input is considered as touch.

Comment: Adding to the questions that `maraca` asked, suppose we had `1`, `+` and `=` and were trying to make `21`.  Could we do it with hitting `1 + 1 = 1 =`?

Comment: I did read it correctly. I quote: "Once you have made the number in Calculator you can copy the number and use it." Imho those are all valid questions and there are more. Maybe the point of the problem is not the implementation but that you ask the interviewer to get a clear specification of the problem. Wouldn't write a single line of code before those questions aren't answered. Welcome to the real world, if you just start writing code I guarantee that you can change everything a dozens of times, because the customer doesn't know what he wants.

Comment: "=" only use to produce result not for concat. You can only type numbers together by   clicking on the allowed number directly. For eg-: [1,2,4,5] is the allowed number and 14 is the result needed,then you can input 1 and 4 on dialpad altogether.

Answer (score 1):

This is a dynamic programming problem that can be solved with a dictionary.  It needs the following data structures:

1. `operation`: A dictionary mapping keys that can be pressed to anonymous functions determining what it does to the state.  Note that numbers are complex operations too, for example `1` applied to a current state of `2` gives you the state `21`.
2. `to_state`: A dictionary mapping states to the fastest path that gets to that state.  Where a path is a Lisp-like list of `[last_operation, [..., [second_operation, [first_operation, None]]...]`  So the path to your example would be `['=', ['4', ['+', ['1', None]]]]`.
3. `upcoming`: A queue of `[state, path]` that can be reached from known states.  It starts off with `['', None]`.
4. `target_state`: The state we want to wind up in.

The heart of the code in Python would be this:

```
while (True):
    state, path = upcoming.shift()
    if state in to_state:
        pass # We have a better route here.
    else:
        to_state[state] = path
        for op, func in operation.iteritems():
            next_state = func(state)
            next_path = [op, path]
            if next_state == 'error':
                pass # Don't need this.
            elif next_state == target_state:
                return next_path
            else:
                upcoming.push([next_state, next_path])
```

I don't program in Java, but it has anonymous functions in the form of lambdas, dictionaries in the form of Maps, and several implementations of queues, including LinkedList.  So it should be relatively straightforward to translate this code.

Of course then you have to write all of the functions, write input code to read the puzzle, and turn the path back into the answer in the form you want it.  So there is a lot of work left to do.